# ModX: Display multiple pages on one page?

Tags: blogs, modx

I have a ModX site and I was wondering if it is at all possible to display multiple pages (including their templates and TVs) on one page? Kind of like a blog?

If anyone could help me out that would be great!

Tnanks

Comment: There are several extras that will probably do this for you [as will getResources] take a look through the blogging extras - http://modx.com/extras/category/blogging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a plugin like [getResources](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/getResources).

It will let you loop through a list of resources like so:

```
[[!getResources? &parents=`[[*id]]` &tpl=`myRowTpl`]]
```

Where the &parents is the parent resource of the items you'd like to list out, and &tpl is the template that would be rendered.

If you're showing TVs don't forget to use

```
&includeTVs=`1` &processTVs=`1`
```

There's tons more info on the modx docs.